# Using SumIfs, array & indirect

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I am using a Countifs formula with an array: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2[End User Class Code],{"MF","MB"})` (there are other criteria but I've left them out for now for simplicity).  This is working fine.

However I would like to change the criteria to refer to a single cell containing the array, as I will sometimes need to change the criteria (MF/MB/etc) it looks for.

I have tried `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Opportunities[End User Class Code],INDIRECT(Sheet3!$F$7)))`, where `Sheet3!F7`=`{"MF","MB"}` however this isn't working.

I trust this makes sense, I'm not 100% au fait with the terminology, but can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: A cell cannot hold an array.  It can hold a string that looks like an array.  INDIRECT will NOT translate a string to an array.  It will only translate a string to a range reference.  Instead refer to a range of cells that contain your values, one per cell.

Comment: Many thanks @ScottCraner, this has helped me to solve this!

Comment: In Office 365 you would be able to use this terminology by adding `=` prior to the value: `={"MF","MB"}` this will make it spill to the right. Refer to the spill range in your formula as `Sheet3!$F$7#`